# Build and dependency tools for objective-c such as ant+ivy / maven?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, build, dependency-management

I'm looking for a good build and dependency tool for objective-c such as ant for build and ivy for dependencies.

I'm aware there are a few maven plugins for xcode :

https://github.com/jendave/maven-xcodebuild-plugin

But I'm looking for the community's read on what's recommended. I don't actually see many resources on this front at all.

There are however lots of links to using Hudson for continuous integration with obj c projects such as :

http://nachbaur.com/blog/how-to-automate-your-iphone-app-builds-with-hudson

I'm looking for more direction on the build side of things.

Answer (score 2):

For dependencies, you could use [CocoaPods](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods). There is a (command line) tool that ships with Xcode called `xcodebuild`. The docs can be found by running `man xcodebuild` from the command line. I don't know of anything that integrates those two, but I could be wrong. You could write a script to combine them, and then call that script from Hudson. The problem with Hudson is that is has to be running on a Mac so it has access to the headers and command line tools.